# what is meant by "from some other part of which it is divided horizontally”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, subordinate-clauses

Concerning the following sentence:

> “flat” means a separate and self-contained set of premises constructed or adapted for use for the purpose of a dwelling and forming part of a building **from some other part of which it is divided horizontally**

What does the bolded section mean?

Comment: A flat forms (is) part of a building. A flat is separated from some other part of the building by a horizontal division.

Comment: "I have some difficulty to understand the passage". So do I. Where the heck did that definition come from???  The definition is ghastly.

Comment: @PhilSweet, does it bother you that somebody actually got paid to write that definition?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply saying (in a rather confusing way) that a "flat" is a part of a multi-story building, and there are other residences or businesses above or below it in the building (vs being, eg, a "duplex" where another residence is to one side with a common wall).

But note that precisely what "flat" means varies widely from one part of the world to another.

Answer (score 0):

First, understand what they mean by

> **flat**
>
> British term for apartment.
>
> [google: flat define](https://www.google.com/search?q=flat&oq=flat&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=flat+define)

So,

> from some other part of which it is divided horizontally

is a fancy way to say the flat has a

> **floor**
>
> flôr
>
> noun
>
> 1. the lower surface of a room, on which one may walk.
>
> "he dropped the cup and it smashed on the floor"
>
> synonyms:  ground, flooring
>
> "he sat on the floor"
>
> [google: floor](https://www.google.com/search?q=flat&oq=flat&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=floor+define)

that is also some other flat's

> **ceiling**
>
> ceil·ing
>
> ˈsēliNG
>
> noun
>
> 1. the upper interior surface of a room or other similar compartment.
>
> synonyms:  upper limit, maximum, limitation
>
> "a ceiling was to be set on prices"
>
> [google: ceiling define](https://www.google.com/search?q=flat&oq=flat&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=ceiling+define)

because the division is

> **horizontal**
>
> hor·i·zon·tal
>
> ˌhôrəˈzän(t)l/Submit
>
> adjective
>
> 1. parallel to the plane of the horizon; at right angles to the vertical.
>
> "a horizontal line"
>
> synonyms:  level, flat, plane, smooth, even; More
>
> 2. merging companies that are engaged in the same stage or type of production.
>
> "a horizontal merger"
>
> noun
>
> 1. a horizontal line, plane, etc.
>
> [google: define horizontal](https://www.google.com/search?q=flat&oq=flat&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=define+horizontal)

If it had been

> **vertical**
>
> ver·ti·cal
>
> ˈvərdək(ə)l/
>
> adjective
>
> 1. at right angles to a horizontal plane; in a direction, or having an alignment, such that the top is directly above the bottom.
>
> "the vertical axis"
>
> [google: define vertical](https://www.google.com/search?q=flat&oq=flat&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=define+vertical)

that would have meant the partition was a

> **wall**
>
> one of the sides of a room or building connecting floor and ceiling or foundation and roof

Comment: Nope. The horizontal division of space is accomplished by a vertical divider, which some of us would call a wall.

Comment: @Phil: No. The same document has a definition of "terrace house" as a dwelling which (a) "shares a party wall with, or has a main wall adjoining the main wall of, the dwelling house on either side" or (b) [paraphrasing] is the end of a row of terrace houses. So "terrace houses" are separated by vertical dividers, not flats (although flats can be separated by vertical dividers as well as horizontal dividers).

Comment: @PeterShor A terrace house is a row house. It has a sense of individual identity that a flat necessarily lacks. It has a private entrance, separate utilities and runs full depth of the building. A terrace house may be divided into flats. The description of the terrace house doesn't really have any bearing on what a flat is. I don't see that it suggests a different meaning for what "divided horizontally" means. I think they just got stuck with that description because the footprint of a flat could be any jigsaw shape.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest difference to illustrate the complex definition.

In order to be called a "flat" there must be more than apartment per floor of a multiple-dwelling building.

If there is only one dwelling per floor of a multiple-dwelling building, it is not referred to as a "flat."

Comment: I don't know where you're from, Stan, your profile doesn't say, but in in England the two dwellings formed from the ground and first floors of a small house are both called 'flats'. (For the sake of people from more logical countries we start numbering our floors from zero and call that one the "ground floor" so a three storey house has a "ground floor", a "first floor" and a "second floor". Don't ask why, we just do.)